# File Path issue while reading config.property file from config reader file

Tags: java, selenium

Reading from excel which kept in other folder named as ExcelFiles,inside it i have my congif.property from where config.reader will read data, part of code is shown below:-

```
try
   {
    File filepath=new File("./InterviewPrep/ExcelFiles/congif.property");
    FileInputStream fileaccess= new FileInputStream(filepath);

    //C:\Users\Pratibha\workspace\InterviewPrep\ExcelFiles\congif.property      //working fine

    prop=new Properties();
    prop.load(fileaccess);

    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("username"));
}
```

When I am using filepath- `"./InterviewPrep/ExcelFiles/congif.property"` 
I am getting an error `filenotfoundexception` but when I am using path-`"C:\Users\Pratibha\workspace\InterviewPrep\ExcelFiles\congif.property"`, code executed successfully.

Why I am getting error with `"./InterviewPrep/ExcelFiles/congif.property"` this filepath?

Comment: You can try this String var = System.getProperty("user.dir"); File filepath=new File(var +"/InterviewPrep/ExcelFiles/congif.property");

Comment: above path what you mentioned will be equivalent to C:\Users\Pratibha\workspace\InterviewPrep\ExcelFiles\congif.property but i am starting my path with "./" that means it will cover till root. I hope i understood correctly.

Comment: Always use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, so that it works fine in cross-platform

Comment: getting an error using user.dir-

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Pratibha\workspace\InterviewPrep\InterviewPrep\ExcelFiles\congif.property (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
 at utility.files.PropertyFileProg.<init>(PropertyFileProg.java:21)
 at utility.files.PropertyFileProg.main(PropertyFileProg.java:37)

Comment: Thank you all, it worked using user.dir now, i committed a mistake while coding but now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PratibhaMishr if you feel my answer help you please mark it as expected. So other can get help from this.

```
 String var = System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
File filepath=new File(var +"/InterviewPrep/ExcelFiles/congif.property");
```

Comment: File filepath=new File(var +"/ExcelFiles/congif.property"); correct one

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```